# MCP73871 Battery Charge Management Board programming resistor question?

Tags: resistors, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am trying to get around the design flaw in a DS3231 real time clock module where it constantly charges the battery, see [ZS-042 DS3231 RTC module](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/zs-042-ds3231-rtc-module/268862) on the Arduino forum.

I was planning to add an MCP73831 (Microchip) based charge management board into the project but I was reading the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf) to calculate the "Prog1" resistor value to fit to the board to work with an LIR2032 battery that has a max discharge current of 35mA and for safety I calculated with 30mA that I need a 33K ohm resistor.

However after reading through the datasheet I am concerned that the undervoltage lockout on that IC is going to kick in at anything less than 100mA and shut everything down, does anyone know if it would?

I apologise for asking, I know this board is a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but I have an abundance of caution around anything that can catch fire and normally I would have tried it with that resistor and measured the output but my box of assorted high value resistors is stuck somewhere in transit.

Stuart.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the 100mA will be below a voltage condition, but it does appear in the datasheet that prog1 has an allowable range of 1k<x<20k ohms unless I'm reading it incorrectly.

Comment: My fault, I misread 100mV for 100mA on page 22 Section 4.1. Thanks for finding that resistance range, means the board isn't going to work for what I want so I will go the supercapacitor route.